# Is it true that every finite sigma algebra is 'isomorphic' to some power set sigma algebra?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, category-theory

Let $(\Omega_1,\mathcal {F_1})$ and $(\Omega_2,\mathcal {F_2})$ be two measurable spaces.we call $\mathcal{F_1}$ and $\mathcal {F_2}$ are isomorphic if there exist a measurable map $f: (\Omega_1,\mathcal {F_1}) \to (\Omega_2,\mathcal {F_2})$ such that the natural map $f_{*}: \mathcal {F_2} \to \mathcal {F_1}$ is bijective and preserves arbitrary union and complements.

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal {F})$ $( \vert \mathcal {F}  \vert < \infty)$ and $(\{0,1\}^k,\mathcal {P}(\{0,1\}^k))$ be measurable spaces. Does there always exist a $k$ such that  $\mathcal {F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal {P}(\{0,1\}^k)$?

I know that cardinality of $\mathcal {F}$ is $2^n$ for some $n$.Any ideas to proceed?

Comment: In other words, must exist two sigma algebras of the same cardinality that preserve union and complement operations for sets of different cardinality.

Comment: Consider the 'atoms' of the space i.e. the equivalence classes given by $x \sim y$ iff ($x \in A$ iff $y \in A$) for each $A \in \Omega$. Give the set of classes the power set algebra. The measurable map that sends each $x \in F$ to its equivalence class induces a bijection on the algebras.

Comment: @basket: Did you mean $x \in \Omega$ instead of $\mathcal {F}$?

Comment: I meant $F$ as in the set being measured, not the algebra of subsets.

Comment: @basket But $f$ should be defined on $\Omega$ right to induce a map between sigma algebras?

Comment: As an example, let $F = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ and $\Omega = \{ \{1,2 \} , \{ 3 \} \}$. Then the 'atoms' or classes are just the sets  $\{1,2 \}$ and $\{ 3 \}$ and the function is $1 \mapsto \{ 1, 2 \}, 2 \mapsto \{ 1, 2 \},  3 \mapsto \{ 3 \}$.

Comment: No a morphism of measurable spaces is a function between the underlying sets $F_1 \to F_2$ that respects the sigma algebras much like a continuous map respects the open sets of the topologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45772/discussion-between-basket-and-victor-barg).